# Hide batch window when using cmd

Tags: batch-file

I'm running a batch file inside another batch file via,

`cmd /c "CopyToModsFolder.bat"`

and in `CopyToModsFolder.bat` I have it keeping the window open via `PAUSE`.

How do I disable `PAUSE` when running it via `cmd` as opposed to just opening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parameters:

#### CopyToModsFolder.bat

```
:: Normal Code for your batch file
:::
:::
:: End of file
if "%~1"=="" pause
```

#### CMD

```
C:\> CopyToModsFolder.bat
...
...
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\> CopyToModsFolder.bat "Param"
...
...

C:\>
```

So using any parameters with your batch file will prevent it from pausing at the end. If your program requires parameters (which you didn't mention in the question). You could simply make it check if the first parameter was something like `"No Pause"` and not pause.